# nginx localhost is downloading php files in browser, instead of serving them?

Tags: php, nginx, localhost

There's an extremely weird thing going on that I have never seen NGINX do, and don't know why it's doing this. I have seen this issue discussed several times at SO, but I haven't found a solution that makes sense for my conf file.

Basically, when I attempt to access a php file through localhost in my browser (any browser), it downloads the file, instead of displaying it. I've read that people think it's a MIME issue, but I can't see where that is reflected in the conf. Additionally, several people said that there was a hidden file in /etc/nginx/conf.d that was overwriting settings. That is not the case here, as far as I can tell. A quick ls -al shows there's nothing in that folder. Help please? :D

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
#   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
#}

#error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
#error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#location = /50x.html {
#   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#   fastcgi_index index.php;
#   include fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not uncomment the entire block. Not only will it fail due to having duplicate `fastcgi_pass` directives, but it won't work regardless. It will continue downloading the files you're requesting instead of serving them to the browser.

Derived from http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi.conf;

    # fastcgi_index index.php;
    # include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I was able to successfully access phpMyAdmin after applying this.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the file looks kind of relevant

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#   fastcgi_index index.php;
#   include fastcgi_params;
#}
```

Try uncommenting it

http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

http://eksith.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/nginx-php-on-windows/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did this, but the downloading bit hasn't changed at all. :/

Comment: You cannot just uncomment all of that section. You have to make a decision or two. See addition links.

Answer (score 2):

You have commented out all of your FastCGI handling for PHP.  Nginx doesn't know how to handle PHP on its own.

Start by un-commenting that block.

Comment: I uncommented the block. The PHP handling hasn't changed, so far.

Comment: @orchd Did you restart the server?  Anything in your error log?  Is FastCGI running?  Is PHP installed?

Comment: Brad, I did restart the server. Since uncommenting all the fastcgi stuff, and restarting, localhost won't even serve html files. PHP5 is installed

Comment: This is the last entry in the error log:              
2014/06/10 13:28:57 [emerg] 3089#0: "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:61

Comment: Since I have php5-fmp, I commented: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; Checking now, to see if that helps...

Comment: No luck. I'm going to reinstall. It's throwing funny errors since I uncommented.

Comment: @orchd Those aren't funny errors, they are errors describing exactly the problem that you need to fix.  Clearly this isn't all of your configuration.  Check for included files.

Comment: That error is because you are uncommenting two fastcgi_pass directives if you uncomment the whole block. One needs to remain commented out.